# Python: dictionary comprehension inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary called `complete_colour_hex` and I want to cut it down to a few entries that are in a list called `used`.

When I run the following I get `'complete_colour_hex' is not defined`.

```
class Colours:

    complete_colour_hex = {
        1:['FFFFFF',15],    2:['9C9C9C',7],     3:['FFE383',18],    4:['F45C40',12],    5:['DEC69C',19],
    }
    used = [1, 2, 3]

    # colour_hex = {}
    # for e in used:
    #     colour_hex[e] = complete_colour_hex[e]
    colour_hex = {e: complete_colour_hex[e] for e in used}

    print(colour_hex)
```

But if I uncomment the three lines and comment the `colour_hex = {e:...` then it works.

Also, either way outside of a class works fine. Why is that in a class, doing it in one line doesn't work?

Comment: Aside: why is this in a class?

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Python 3.